# How to create dynamic content inside dynamic content in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, getelementbyid

I get null when I try to do getelementbyid on dynamic loaded in div
I tried window.onload = function () { and $(window).load(function() {

index.html:

```
<main >

    <div id="main-div">

    </div>

</main>
```

homepage.html:

```
<!-- categories Slider -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="site-slider-two px-md-4">
        <div class="row slider-two text-center" id="homepageCategories">
```

javascript:

```
function loadHomePage() {

    $("#main-div").load("homepage.html", function () {
}
}

function showCategoriesHomepage(categories) {

    window.onload = function () {

        homepageCategoriesId = document.getElementById(homepageCategories);

        homepageCategoriesId.innerHTML = "";

        //For loop that loops true all the categories
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

            //Create dynamic li elements with child p elements
            var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            var img = document.createElement('img');


            span.setAttribute("class", "border site-btn btn-span");

            img.setAttribute("src", categories.image);

            //Fills the p elements with user_id, description, created_at
            span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(categories.name));
            mainDiv.appendChild(img);
            mainDiv.appendChild(span);
}
}
```

After the homepage is loaded I make a call to the api and after that is finished I try to getelementbyid on the div but it returns null

Comment: When/where are you calling `showCategoriesHomepage` function? Did you read the jQuery `load()` [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/)? The method provides a callback, why not use it? Why do you use `window.onload` from within your function? You need to provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the problem and describe clearly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line...

```
homepageCategoriesId = document.getElementById(homepageCategories);
```

...to this

```
homepageCategoriesId = document.getElementById('homepageCategories');
```

Comment: thats when you know you have programmed for to long XD

Comment: @ThomasPonzo I know that sir haha